# GroupBy Alphabetically one list to Another

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of the following object:

```
public class userReview
{
    public long item { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public decimal? quatity { get; set; }
}
```

Some details:
-Items and Users are many to many
-User B dont need to have a record to item A like user A does (so, he wont have a quantity for that. The new objecti will recieve a blank. Ill show it).

I need to make a list of each quantity of one item by user. The object would be like:

```
public class listItem
{
    public long item { get; set; }
    public List<string> quatityList { get; set; }
}
```

Each member of quatityList correspond a different user, before any interation Ill need to sort alphabetically all users. My biggest problem with the solutions I made until now is that I need to record a blank space if that user didnt have a record with that specific item.

Comment: are you adding all your userReview objects to a list ?? than you can easily sort the list using linq

Comment: Yeah, As described "I have a list of the following object:" .. I got some problems with combinations of LINQ and Objects.

Comment: `var newList = userReview.OrderBy(x=>x.User).ToList();` will get you a new ordered list alphabetically than you can check the values an create new list with comparison you want not sure if that what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a list of `userReview` and you want to **group by** the `item` property into a collection of `listItem`.

With LINQ,

```
List<userReview> userReviews = GetItems();

var groups = userReviews.GroupBy(u => u.item);
var listItems = groups.Select(group => 
    new listItem()
    { 
        item = group.Key,
        quantityList = group.Select(g => g.User).ToList()
     }).ToList();
```

I also strongly agree with Darjan - learn about coding standards. Classes and Properties should always be capitalised.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your answer almost fits my requirements. I just changed to `(g => g.User)` to `(g => g.quatity.ToString())` ..Anyway, Im still with the following problem: its possible to USER2 dont have a record with its quantity to ITEM1 inside `userReviews` list while USER1 does, in this case I'll need to add a blank space into `quantityList`. By now, its not adding anything. In other words: If I have 4 users, Ill need to have 4 recordes inside each record of `quantityList`,

Comment: @Dan-SP You want a blank record when a user doesn't have an item? What about users that don't have any items - how do you know who they are? Strongly recommend you look at your data modelling and read some books to learn how to structure your objects.

Comment: Hi Kirk. I wont have users without any item (they will have at least one). I might have users without a item eventually. There's no problem with my data modeling since its a conference (the user A make a conference of quantity X about item Y) and as users are different people they might miss any item conference. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

```
var users = new List<string>();
//fill users ... 

var items = new List<long>();
//fill items ... 

var userReviews = new List<UserReview>();
//fill userReviews (not each user reviews all atems) ... 

var listItems = new List<ListItem>();

//actual code to fill listItems 
foreach (var item in items)
{
    users.Sort();
    var listItem = new ListItem() {Item = item, QuantityList = new List<string>()};
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var review = userReviews.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Item == item && x.User == user);
        listItem.QuantityList.Add(review != null ? review.Quantity.ToString() : "-");
    }
    listItems.Add(listItem);
}
```

This should do, but I advise you to learn about coding standards in C# and try to consistently use them.

The code above is not optimal, if you have a lot of records, make sure not to search the whole list each time, and of course, reconsider the design of your whole model.